# Power BI Report Server: Can't upload this report. We can't save this Power BI Desktop report because it is newer version or has component parts tha

Tags: powerbi

We are trying to upload a really basic BI Report to a newly installed instance of Power BI Report Server but unable to do so.

All we are getting is the error

**"Power BI Report Server: Can't upload this report. We can't save this Power BI Desktop report because it is newer version or has component parts that are not supported."**

instead.

Googling the issue, most posts say make sure the version of Power BI Report Server being uploaded to is later than that of the instance of Power BI Desktop being used to create the report.

I have created the report using both January 2020 and May 2019 instances of Power BI Desktop.

Attempts to upload both fail with the same error.

Some further version info is below.

I have rebooted the server to make sure any configuration changes to BI Power Report Server  are applied.

Anyone got any other suggestions?

Thanks

According to Report Server Configuration Manager we have version 15.0.2.389 of Power BI Report Server - Developer installed.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/changelog, the January 2020 Release is version: 1.6.7364.4075 (Build 15.0.1102.777) which suggests the version installed is later than this.

The version of Power BI Desktop being used is the January 2020 release Product Version 2.76.5678.1521 (19.12) (x64).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can look into:

Microsoft does release minor updates (mostly with bug fixes) ... and there was a minor release in March 2020 i believe ...  which might be causing the issue.

Secondly are you sure you are using Power BI Desktop **(Report server version)** ?